# Como obtener datos de la base de datos de SQL Server mediante Python y tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, tkinter

Estoy intentando ejecutar el siguiente script que es para obtener los datos que se encuentran en una base SQL SERVER y mostrarlos en una lista con tkinter, pero no obtengo ni los resultados deseados ni un mensaje de error, y no puedo averiguar dónde lo estoy haciendo mal.
Este es el código usado para la ejecución del comando SQL

```
def returnAllElements(self):
        sql = "SELECT * FROM FAMILIAS"
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        return self.cursor
```

y este es para mostrarlos

```
if ref == "":
        #fill list
            d = R_familia()
            elements = d.returnAllElements()
            for fl in elements:
                for cl in fl:
                    self.lst_pod.insert('', 'end' , values=cl)
        else:
            d = R_familia()
            elements = d.ReturnForCaracter(ref)
            for fl in elements:
                for cl in fl:
                    self.lst_pod.insert('', 'end' , values=cl)
                #self.lst_pod.insert('', 'end', values=fl)
```

y me da un resultado así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se que me falta, me pueden ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

No conozco lo que devuelve el iterar sobre el cursor en este modulo de bases de datos, así que asumo que se trata de una lista de tuplas (lista de filas).
Si esto es cierto, entonces estás usando mal el parametro values. values acepta un iterable en donde cada elemento corresponde a una respectiva columna. Por ejemplo el elemento 1 va en la primera columna, el 2 en la segunda y así.

Eso significa, que alcanza con iterar sobre la lista y así obtendrás una tupla que será la fila a agregar. De hecho, en tu else tenés en forma de comentario `self.lst_pod.insert('', 'end', values=fl)` que era la manera de hacerlo.

Ejemplo:

```
elements = d.returnAllElements()
for fl in elements:
    self.lst_pod.insert('', 'end' , values=fl)
```

Comment: esa era la manera en la que lo estaba trabajando pero me me devolvía una dupla en de la forma ('1, 'cuidados .....' datetime.date(2020-09-2020)), la verdad no entiendo muy bien por que

Comment: Como es eso? Podrías editar la pregunta y poner alguna imagen y descripción de lo que sucede por favor? Lo pido para entender mejor que sucede, pues esta es la manera que uso habitualmente y me funciona bien.

Comment: le agradezco mucho, ya encontré el error, `self.lst_pod.insert('', 'end', values=(fl[0], fl[1], fl[2]))` con esto lo solucione.